# React JS removeEventListener not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two functions with one containing addEventListener("click") and the other to remove

```
show() {
    console.log("SHOW FUNCTION")
    this.setState({
        listVisible: true
    })

    document.addEventListener("click", this.hide.bind(this));
}

hide() {
    console.log("HIDE FUNCTION")
    this.setState({
        listVisible: false
    })

    document.removeEventListener("click", this.hide.bind(this));
}
```

On initial click, show() is fired, state is updated as expected and once the second click is made hide() is fired and all is well.

When I click again ( third click ) my console.logs list show() first and then two logs for hide() thus setting my state back to false when it should be true, just like the first sequence.

I'm unsure as to why this is happening, it's almost as if the removeEventListener isn't firing. Could also be wrong context of "this"?

Here is my component code:

```
renderListItems() {
    const items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.props.list.length; i++) {
        const item = this.props.list[i];
        items.push(<div className="option" onClick={() => this.select(item)}>
            <span>{item.name}</span>
            <i className="fa fa-check"></i>
        </div>);
    }
    return items;
}

render() {
    console.log("give me", this.state.listVisible)
    return (
        <div className={"dropdown-container" + (this.state.listVisible ? " show" : "")}>
            <div className={"dropdown-display" + (this.state.listVisible ? " clicked": "")} onClick={() => this.show()}>
                <span>
                    {this.state.selected.name}
                </span>
                <i className="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            </div>
            <div className="dropdown-list">
                <div>
                    {this.renderListItems()}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `.bind` it is creating a new function. You should create the bound function once when the component is created so that the removeEventListener can find the function.

You can bind class methods in ES6:

```
hide = () => {

}
```

Or do it in your constructor:

```
constructor(...args) {
   super(...args);
   this.hide = this.hide.bind(this);
}
```

Then your event listener can simply refer to the already bound function `this.hide`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - to remove the hide function, remove all binds and update state within the select function.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import classNames from 'classnames';

import './style.scss'

export default class FormCustomSelect extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            listVisible: false,
            display: "",
            selected: this.props.selected
        }
    }

    select(item) {
         this.setState({ 
            selected: item,
            listVisible: false
         })
    }

    show() {        
        this.setState({
            listVisible: true
        })
    }

    renderListItems() {
        const items = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.props.list.length; i++) {
            const item = this.props.list[i];
            items.push(<div className="option" onClick={() => this.select(item)}>
                <span>{item.name}</span>
                <i className="fa fa-check"></i>
            </div>);
        }
        return items;
    }

    render() {
        console.log("give me", this.state.listVisible)

        return (
            <div className={"dropdown-container" + (this.state.listVisible ? " show" : "")}>
                <div className={"dropdown-display" + (this.state.listVisible ? " clicked": "")} onClick={() => this.show()}>
                    <span>
                        {this.state.selected.name}
                    </span>
                    <i className="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </div>
                <div className="dropdown-list">
                    <div>
                        {this.renderListItems()}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```